# Getting the maximum Pair Wise product C++ and the output is not always right with my code

Tags: c++, algorithm, code-testing

Problem to solve:
given an array or sequence of numbers the goal is to find the Max number obtained by the multiplication of some 2 numbers in that sequence.

example of inputs and outputs

```
Input:
2
100000 90000

Correct output:
9000000000

Input:
3
1 2 3

Correct output:
6
```

My Solution: get the 2 Maximum numbers in the sequence given and multiply them
my code works unless with one solution

My code

```
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;
void print(std::vector<int> const& input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << input.at(i) << '   ';
    }
}

int main()
{
   
    vector<int> seq;
    int n;

    // Read the nb of elements in vect
    cout << "please enter the number of elements in sequence"<<endl;
    cin >> n;

    // Read the vector 
    cout << "please enter the elements of the sequence"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        seq.push_back(input);
    }
    cout << "sequence you entered" << endl;
    print(seq);


    // Find the 1st max element 
    double FisrtMax=*max_element(seq.begin(), seq.end());
    cout <<endl<< "First Maximum Element is" << endl<< FisrtMax;

    // remove the found element
    std::vector<int>::iterator PosF = find(seq.begin(), seq.end(), FisrtMax);
    seq.erase(PosF);

    cout <<endl<< "sequence After removing the 1st maximum element" << endl;
    print(seq);


    // Find the 2nd max element
    double SecMax = *max_element(seq.begin(), seq.end());
    cout <<endl<< "Second Maximum Element is" << endl << SecMax;

    //multiply the 2 elements
    int total =  (FisrtMax * SecMax);
    cout <<endl<<"The Product of the 2 elemnts is  "<< total;

    return 0;
}
```

The Input :

```
please enter the number of elements in sequence
2
please enter the elements of the sequence
1000000
90000
```

The Output :

```
please enter the number of elements in sequence
2
please enter the elements of the sequence
1000000
90000
sequence you entered
10000002105376900002105376
First Maximum Element is
1e+06
sequence After removing the 1st maximum element
900002105376
Second Maximum Element is
90000
The Product of the 2 elements is  -2147483648
```

Comment: The maximum value for an `int` is `2147483647`. Can't hold the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are several mistakes in the code:**

1. `cout << ... << '   '` syntax tries to print *three* whitespace *characters* letters using a single-quote which accepts a single letter not multiple. Use `"   "` instead.
2. The result produced can't be held by an integer, you need to define `size_t` (which expands into `unsigned long long` in most compilers).

**Side Tips:**

- In this syntax:

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
  ```

  You're trying to compare an integer to `size_t` (returned by `size()` member function of vector class object). Rather than that, declare `i` with `size_t`.
- In this syntax:

  ```
   std::vector<int>::iterator PosF = find(seq.begin(), seq.end(), FisrtMax);
  ```

  You don't need to define such long type `std::vector<int>::iterator`, use `auto` keyword here:

  ```
   auto PosF = find(seq.begin(), seq.end(), FirstMax);
  ```

---

**Code redefined:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(std::vector<size_t> const &input) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        std::cout << input.at(i) << "   ";
}

int main(void) {
    vector<size_t> seq;
    int n;

    // Read the nb of elements in vect
    cout << "please enter the number of elements in sequence" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    // Read the vector
    cout << "please enter the elements of the sequence" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        seq.push_back(input);
    }
    cout << "sequence you entered" << endl;
    print(seq);

    // Find the 1st max element
    double FisrtMax = *max_element(seq.begin(), seq.end());
    cout << endl
         << "First Maximum Element is" << endl
         << FisrtMax;

    // remove the found element
    auto PosF = find(seq.begin(), seq.end(), FisrtMax);
    seq.erase(PosF);

    cout << endl << "sequence After removing the 1st maximum element" << endl;
    print(seq);

    // Find the 2nd max element
    double SecMax = *max_element(seq.begin(), seq.end());

    cout << endl
         << "Second Maximum Element is" << endl
         << SecMax;

    //multiply the 2 elements
    size_t total = (FisrtMax * SecMax);
    
    cout << endl
         << "The Product of the 2 elements is  " << total;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Its Inputs:**

```
please enter the number of elements in sequence
2
please enter the elements of the sequence
1000000
90000
```

**It outputs:**

```
sequence you entered
1000000   90000
First Maximum Element is
1e+06
sequence After removing the 1st maximum element
90000   
Second Maximum Element is
90000
The Product of the 2 elemnts is  90000000000
```

**Edit:** This program successfully works on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BkiqFDBJw) and the program was compiled with C++14 flag.

Comment: thank you for the help
i have tried it but still is not right
the output was

`The Product of the 2 elements is  4294967295`

Comment: @SimoneFarid This isn't possible, the code is working fine on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BkiqFDBJw).

Comment: I copy pasted your code, this is the output and i am using VS

Comment: It works on Online GDB too but not VS do you have any idea what is the cause

Comment: @SimoneFarid It might be a compiler issue. Try to run it with `g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp` command.